# Renaming columns lazily in dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

The function `merge_dataframes` below takes a list of dask dataframes and merges them into one final dataframe. The requirement is as follows: if the number of dataframes in the list is greater than one, then the columns of each dataframe will be renamed as `_N_column-name` where N is the sequence of the dataframe in the list (starting from 1) and column-name is the original column name in the dataframe. If the number of dataframes is one, then no renaming takes place (and no merging).

In the code below there are three dataframes, and the final dataframe should have the following columns: `_1_id, _1_balance, _1_count, _2_id, _2_balance, _2_count, _3_id, _3_balance, _3_count`

The problem is that the compute triggers the dask functions after the loop takes place, that means that `i = 2` for all the `dd.rename` functions, not each dataframe with its `i`.  Therefore the code throws the following exception on the compute():

> ValueError: The columns in the computed data do not match the columns
> in the provided metadata
> Extra:   ['_3_balance', '_3_count']
> Missing: ['_2_balance', '_2_count']

How to fix this?

```
pdf1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'balance': [10, 20, 30],
    'count': [1, 1, 1]
})
pdf2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'balance': [100, 200, 300],
    'count': [1, 1, 1]
})
pdf3 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3],
    'balance': [1000, 2000, 3000],
    'count': [1, 1, 1]
})

ddf1 = dd.from_pandas(pdf1, npartitions=2) 
ddf1 = ddf1.set_index('id')
ddf2 = dd.from_pandas(pdf2, npartitions=2) 
ddf2 = ddf2.set_index('id')
ddf3 = dd.from_pandas(pdf3, npartitions=2) 
ddf3 = ddf3.set_index('id')

def merge_dataframes(ddfs):
    
    for i, ddf in enumerate(ddfs):
        if i == 0:
            ddf2 = ddf
        else:
            if i == 1:
                ddf2 = ddf2.rename(columns=lambda x: f'_1_{x}')
                
            prefix = f'_{i+1}_'   
            ddf = ddf.rename(columns=lambda x: prefix + x)
            ddf2 = ddf2.merge(ddf, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
            
    return ddf2

ddfs = [ ddf1, ddf2, ddf3 ]
ddf_final = merge_dataframes(ddfs)
ddf_final.compute()
```

Comment: I have make an answer where I add suffixes instead of prefix, if you really need prefixes to be let me know. Also let m know if you want the first data frame to have _0_ prefix/suffix. I understood from your code, you dont

Comment: I really need prefixes instead of suffixes starting with _1_, not _0_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the followng code

```py
import re

def merge_dataframes(ddfs):
    ddf2 = ddfs[0]
    cols_count = iter([i for num, df in enumerate(ddfs) 
                       for i in [num+1]*len(df.columns)])
    initial_columns  = ddfs[0].columns
    for i, ddf in enumerate(ddfs[1:]):
        ddf2 = ddf2.merge(ddf, how='inner', left_index=True,
                          right_index=True)
        
    
    return ddf2.rename(columns=lambda x: f'_{next(cols_count)}_{re.sub("_x|_y", "", x)}')

ddfs = [ddf1, ddf2, ddf3 ]
ddf_final = merge_dataframes(ddfs)
ddf_final.compute()
```

output

```
   _1_balance   _1_count    _2_balance    _2_count   _3_balance  _3_count
id                      
1      10          1          100           1          1000         1
2      20          1          200           1          2000         1
3      30          1          300           1          3000         1
```

**Note** I have also simplified the if/else statements, which I though make more complex the readability of the code and I from my point of view there is no need for them.

Comment: In your example the suffix 3 is missing, in any case suffixes will NOT work because the second merge will not generate any suffixes because the field names are not different. look at the example in the question.

Comment: I have updated for suffixes, so that all dataframes have a value (which is what I was asking in the comment I did in the question). Moreover, The code **works perfectly**  I always verified the code of my answers before posting it. Note that  in the loop the first columns for the first dataframe is not modified and thus every time in the  loop new suffix are generated. The edit I have done now modified it at the end for the first dataframe.If you want I can think how to do it with prefixes if it is really needed.

Comment: I have added a last step for changing the suffixes into prefixes

Comment: Lucas, there's a problem with your function. If the column names are not identical (for example `count_a`, `count_b`, `count_c` instead of `count` this doesn't work, it should return `_1_count_a`, `_2_count_b`, `_3_count_c`

Comment: That totally change the optic, from the data you have given I thought all dataframes had the same names for all the columns. Let me think how can we do this

Comment: @ps0604, updated for the new situation